# Ajax Slider Rating System (not Star Rating)

Tags: ajax, slider, rating

I'm looking for a Ajax rating script similar to the one on metacritic, ign, gamespot, etc.
([example](http://www.metacritic.com/game/wii/super-mario-galaxy-2))

I've found only star rating systems and one slider that is not similar to the one that I'm looking for. ([jquery ui slider](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/slider_v2/index.php))

Anyone knows something like that I'm looking for? Otherwise I'm willing to pay someone for this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard to roll your own, you just need a combination of jQuery/AJAX, CSS and the server-side poison of your choice.

Here is an example: 
http://www.99points.info/2010/05/ajax-rating-system-create-simple-ajax-rating-system-using-jquery-ajax-and-php/

Essentially you wire up client-side event handlers which do AJAX HTTP POST requests to your server-side handler/web service, which then return back the response.

Now, that example isn't exactly a "slider" but it illustrates how it can be accomplished.

Check out [this](http://www.noupe.com/javascript/30-javascriptajax-techniques-for-sliders-scrollers-and-scrollbars.html) site for a multitude of AJAX slider examples - you just need to combine the two principles (rating and slider) and you're good to go.

Obviously if you don't like the "look" of it, you can mess with the CSS/hovering effects to suit your needs, but that should get you up and running.